# How to use __init__ method in Python?

Tags: python, class

I'm creating a hex class for hexadecimal values. The `__init__` method is expecting a hex string, but I want to be able to create a Hex instance from an integer in decimal, so I create a method for that. The code is as follows:

```
class Hex:

    def __init__(self, val):
        #val should be a hex string
        self.val = val

    def from_dec(self, x):
        self.__init__(self, hex(x))
```

However, when I run:

```
a = Hex.from_dec(20)
print a.val
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unbound method from_dec() must be called with Hex instance 
as first argument (got int instance instead)
```

How do I use `__init__` properly?

Comment: If you want an alternative constructor, you can use `@classmethod` to create one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One fairly idiomatic way would be to make `from_dec` a classmethod:

```
class Hex:

    def __init__(self, val):
        #val should be a hex string
        self.val = val

    @classmethod
    def from_int(cls, x):
        return(Hex(hex(x)))

print Hex('0xab').val
print Hex.from_int(99).val
```

Comment: Wouldn't the signature of `from_dec` be something like `from_dec(cls, x)` instead of `from_dec(self, x)`?

Answer (score 2):

The first argument of your method `from_dec` is `self`, which means that an object of the class `Hex` is expected.

I would create a method outside the class to create hex objects from a decimal input.

```
def from_dec(x):
    return Hex(hex(x))

class Hex:

    def __init__(self, val):
        #val should be a hex string
        self.val = val
```

Or change the input arguments of the constructor.

```
class Hex:

    def __init__(self, val, dec=False):
        #val should be a hex string, unless dec=True
        if dec:
            self.val = hex(val)
        else:
            self.val = val

h = Hex(20, dec=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling class' function do NOT include first parameter (read python doc about classes!).

this is going to work properly:

```
def from_dec(self, x):
    self.__init__(hex(x))
```

however, it's going to be better to assign to variable, not to use **init**, which should be run only during initialization of object.

```
def from_dec(self, x):
    self.val = hex(self.val)
```

Comment: the former still does not work, gives the same error: TypeError: unbound method from_dec() must be called with Hex instance as first argument (got int instance instead)

Comment: oh, sorry, you need firstly to create your class and then call from_dec using class. or use @classmethod, as shown by bsa